# trying to query rows of a bridge table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a bridge table:

```
PersonTagMap
ID         Autonumber
PersonFK   Integer Foreign key --to Person Table
TagFK      Integer Foreign key --to Tage Table
```

The data is simple:

```
ID       PersonFK        TAGFK
1        1               1
2        1               2
3        2               1
4        3               1
5        1               4
6        1               5
```

etc...

I need:

to find all PersonFKs where the logic is as follows:
either 1 OR 2 AND
either 3 OR 4 AND
either 5 OR 6

so PERSONS who has TAGS `1,3,5 or 1,3,6 or 1,4,5 or 1,4,6 or 2,3,5 or 2,3,6 or 2,4,5 or 2,4,6`

I tried:

```
select PersonFK from PeopleTagMap PTM 
where (PTM.peopletagid = 1 or PTM.peopletagid = 2) AND 
(PTM.peopletagid =3 or PTM.peopletagid = 4) AND 
(PTM.peopletagid =5 or PTM.peopletagid = 6)
```

but if I use the example data above, I do not get a response, even though person 1 does have combination `1,4,5`.

Any wisdom would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use following query

```
    DECLARE @tblPerson AS TABLE( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
                             PersonFK INT,
                             TAGFK INT)
INSERT INTO @tblPerson(PersonFK,TAGFK)
     VALUES(1,1), (1,2) , (2,1),   (3,1),   (1,4),   (1,5)


SELECT PersonFK
FROM @tblPerson 
WHERE (TAGFK =1 OR TAGFK =2) 
INTERSECT
SELECT PersonFK
FROM @tblPerson 
WHERE (TAGFK =3 OR TAGFK =4) 
INTERSECT
SELECT PersonFK
FROM @tblPerson 
WHERE (TAGFK =5 OR TAGFK =6)
```

Comment: Thanks much Rajat!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` and `having` for this purpose:

```
select PersonFK
from PeopleTagMap PTM 
group by PersonFK
having sum(case when PTM.peopletagid = 1 or PTM.peopletagid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when PTM.peopletagid = 3 or PTM.peopletagid = 4 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when PTM.peopletagid = 5 or PTM.peopletagid = 6 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```